# Function selector of function that takes enum as argument

Tags: solidity, abi, function-selector

If a function takes an enum as a parameter

```
function foo(MyEnum arg1, uint256 arg2) public returns (bool);
```

how do I properly compute the function selector for that function?

Answer (score 3):

If you compile a contract with that function in it and take a look at the generated ABI, you'll see that the enum parameter ends up being a `uint8`. So compute the selector like this:

```
web3.sha3('foo(uint8,uint256)').substring(0,10) === '0xfec108d0'
```